# Correct way to initialize tensor in ARM compute library?

Tags: c++11, initialization, arm, tensor

What is the correct way to initialize a tensor in the ARM compute library? I have not found any documentation on what is the correct way to do it.

The tensor I have contains floats (F32). I can write data directly by accessing the underlying data through the buffer() interface, which returns a pointer to uint8_t. However, I am not sure how to figure out the data layout because it does not appear to be contiguous, i.e. if I write 4 floats to a 4x1 tensor,

```
Tensor x{};

x.allocator()->init(TensorInfo(4, 1, Format::F32));

float xdata[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; 
FILE *fd = fmemopen(x.buffer(), 4 * sizeof(float), "wb");
fwrite(xdata, sizeof(float), 4, fd);
fclose(fd);

x.print(std::cout);
```

This prints out,

> 1           2           3 1.17549e-38

The fist 3 elements of 'x' are initialized, but the last one is not. If I change the fwrite line to,

```
fwrite(xdata, sizeof(float), 6, fd);
```

then the output is

> 1 2 3 4

So it may be that there are more bytes being allocated than necessary for 4 floats, or this could be some misleading coincidence. Either way, this is not the right way to initialize the values of the tensor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From arm compute library documentation (v18.08), looks like the right way to initialize in your case would be "import_memory" function. See example here: https://github.com/ARM-software/ComputeLibrary/blob/master/tests/validation/NEON/UNIT/TensorAllocator.cpp

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to allocate the tensor as well.

More precisely

```
Tensor x{};

x.allocator()->init(TensorInfo(4, 1, Format::F32)); Set the metadata
x.allocator()->allocate(); // Now the memory has been allocated

float xdata[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; 
memcpy(x.data(), xdata, 4 * sizeof(float), "wb");

x.print(std::cout);
```

This code is not tested, but it should give you a fairly good idea!